# validation on has_many association depending type of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

so what I am trying to accomplish might be very simple but i cannot get my head around it. I have subscribe user and a regular user. Regular users are only allowed to post 4 time while current user subscribed is allowed to post 10 times. Below is the code I have right now which works perfect but the validation only works on all type of user.

```
  class Post < ApplicationRecord
    validate :validates_posts!, on: :create

    private

    def validates_posts!
       return if user.nil?
        if user.posts.count > 4
          errors.add(:base, 'Cannot add more than 4 Ads at a time')
        end
    end
```

Comment: We'd need to see how regular and subscriber users are defined (separate models, one column difference), but whatever it is, just add that to the if, `if user.regular? && users.posts.count > 4`

Comment: How are you defining the roles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 if user.role == 'role1' && user.posts.count > 4
    errors.add(:base, 'Cannot add more than 4 Ads at a time')
 elsif user.type == 'role2' && user.post.count > 10
    errors.add(:base, 'Cannot add more than 10 Ads at a time')
 end
```